# I got confused with a custom function in javascript that gets an object as an arguement

Tags: javascript

I'm testing that piece of code but, I don't understand why is not working properly. The myFunc function is getting as an arguement an object. Then it checks if it is really an object and if it is, then the function alerts the value of the length property. Otherwise, it alerts the corresponding message. But, I get mind-blown when it alerts 'Its not an object!'.

I don't get it. Can you help me out please?

```
var myObject = new Object();

myObject ={
    length: 400
};

alert(typeof(myObject));

function myFunc(obj) {

    if (typeof(obj) == "object") {
        return console.log(this.length);
    } else {
        alert('Its not an object!');
    }
};

var a = myFunc.call(myObject); 
var b = myFunc(myObject); 

alert(a);
alert(b);
```

Comment: What about `obj instanceof Object` ?

Comment: I replaced the part: `typeof(obj) == true ` with the `obj instanceof Object == true` but it still not working. But when I removed the if statement and the argument obj from the function, it alerted 400.

Comment: Yep, It's related to the @sepulchered answer. The first parameter of Function.call is the `thisArg` and not the first argument. See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should avoid using the `typeof` operator when it comes to checking the actual type of a variable.

In JavaScript all the variable types that are passed by reference (Array, Object, Function, `typeof null` will also return Object) will return Object when calling the `typeof` operator on them. You should instead use `instanceof`:

```
// Example with Array - it is of type Object but instance of Array
var array = [1,2,3];

typeof array; // Object
array instanceof Array; // true
```

Also, be aware that `Objects` do not have the `length` property. If you would like to see if the `length` property was defined on an Object, you can access it in various ways.

**Check if it is an own property:**

```
// returns true only if the property was defined on this instance and not on the prototype chain

if(myObject.hasOwnProperty("length")) {
    // code goes here
}
```

**Check if the property exists on the object (through the prototype chain as well):**

```
if(myObject.length) {
    // code goes here
}
```

Also, `Function.prototype.call()` takes two parameters:

1. The value of `this`
2. The arguments for the function that you are calling

You can read more about `Function.prototype.call()` at the following [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: You answer is really helpful @Vlad Z. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sergiti I'm glad that I could help you out :)

Answer (score 2):

First when you write `func.call(someObj)` you set `this` of that function to `someObj` thus in your variant you get argument set to `undefined` as you don't provide any arguments at all and `typeof undefined == undefined`.

Second problem: you `return console.log(this.length);` - `console.log()` doesn't return any value thus you get undefined as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your code is -

1: You are returning console.log method.

2: When you are calling method using call method you are not passing this to your method so it'll undefined.

Comment: He doesn't use length method of arrary. There is length property defined in `myObject`.